# Grinder JDBC test script error" The result of 'TestRunner()' is not callable"

Tags: python, jython, grinder

I use JDBC.py script run  performance testing . grinder log info:

> 2015-10-14 18:42:40,132 ERROR com-0 thread-24: aborting thread - {}The result of 'TestRunner()' is not callable
>   net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: The result of 'TestRunner()' is not callable
>           at net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptEngine.createWorkerRunnable(JythonScriptEngine.java:183) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
>           at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess$ThreadStarterImplementation$2.create(GrinderProcess.java:784) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
>           at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderThread.run(GrinderThread.java:90) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
>   2015-10-14 18:42:40,132 ERROR com-0 thread-3: aborting thread - {}The result of 'TestRunner()' is not callable
>   net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: The result of 'TestRunner()' is not callable
>           at net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptEngine.createWorkerRunnable(JythonScriptEngine.java:183) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
>           at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess$ThreadStarterImplementation$2.create(GrinderProcess.java:784) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
>           at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderThread.run(GrinderThread.java:90) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]

I modify script, but still  error. Please help check it.

I  test script :

```
# The sorting tes  supports a configurable array length.
# It runs the JavaTest.sort method of the JavaTest class.

from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.script import Test
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from java.sql import DriverManager
from oracle.jdbc import OracleDriver

########################################
#
# main body of test script starts here
#
########################################

# Get the propeties to access test configuration information
properties = grinder.getProperties()

# The description is a property (instead of a hardcoded string in this script)
#test = Test(1, properties.get("javatest.description"))
test = Test(2, properties.get("javatest.description"))

# select the method for which to collect information
# test.record(WriteMulitpleLittleFile.write)

# initialize data for compressing
# fileName = properties.get("javatest.fileToCompress")
# grinder.logger.info("data file to compress is " + fileName)
# JavaTest.initializeCompression(fileName)

# If the run mode is runOnce, the TestRunner class will
# run once.  Otherwise, if the run mode is continuous,
# the TestRunner class will run the test for at least
# the specified duration (but possibly longer)
runMode = properties.get("javatest.runMode")
#WriteMulitpleLittleFile.setParameters(dir, fileSize...)
if runMode == "continuous":
  # figure out how long to run the test
  m = int(properties.getProperty("javatest.durationMinutes", "0"))
  h = int(properties.getProperty("javatest.durationHours", "0"))
  d = int(properties.getProperty("javatest.durationDays", "0"))
  duration = timedelta(minutes=m,hours=h,days=d)
  grinder.logger.info("run mode is continuous, duration is " + str(duration))
elif runMode == "runOnce":
  grinder.logger.info("run mode is run once")
  duration = timedelta(minutes=0)
else:
  grinder.logger.info("run mode not set or not recongized, default to run once")
  duration = timedelta(minutes=0)

########################################
#
# The TestRunner class is used by The Grinder to perform the test
#
########################################

#test1 = Test(1, "Database insert")
test2 = Test(2, "Database query")

# Load the Oracle JDBC driver.
DriverManager.registerDriver(OracleDriver())

def getConnection():
    return DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@den00bvr.us.oracle.com:1521:orcl", "PBPUBLIC", "PBPUBLIC")

def ensureClosed(object):
    try: object.close()
    except: pass

# One time initialisation that cleans out old data.
connection = getConnection()
statement = connection.createStatement()

#try: statement.execute("drop table grinder_test1126")
#except: pass

#statement.execute("create table grinder_test1126(thread number, run number)")

ensureClosed(statement)
ensureClosed(connection)

class TestRunner:
   def __init__(self):
#        tid = grinder.threadNumber

#        if (grinder.threadNumber % 2 == 0):
#             Even threadNumber
#             Do insertStatement
#        else:
#             Odd threadNumber
#             Do queryStatement

#   def __call__(self):
#       self.testRunner()

        endTime = datetime.now() + duration
        notDone = True
        while notDone:
         connection = None
         insertStatement = None
         queryStatement = None
         notDone = datetime.now() < endTime

        try:
            connection = getConnection()
#           insertStatement = connection.createStatement()
            queryStatement = connection.createStatement()

#           test1.record(insertStatement)
#           insertStatement.execute("insert into grinder_test1126 values(%d, %d)" %
#                                   (grinder.threadNumber, grinder.runNumber))

            test2.record(queryStatement)
            queryStatement.execute("select * from employee")

        finally:
#           ensureClosed(insertStatement)
            ensureClosed(queryStatement)
            ensureClosed(connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation,

> The TestRunner instance must be callable
>
> A Python object is callable if it defines a **call** method. Each
>   worker thread performs a number of runs of the test script, as
>   configured by the property grinder.runs. For each run, the worker
>   thread calls its TestRunner; thus the **call** method can be thought
>   of as the definition of a run.

Your script requires a **call** function in order to be classified as callable.